# how do you setup dyanamic routing in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, slug

I'm trying to set dynamic routing in an asp.net core 3.1 MVC application. I need something like [www.mysite.com/USERID/shop](http://www.mysite.com/USERID/shop).  Want to be able to read USERID and all routing for all other pages append and work as usual.  I need the userid for sharing URLs, but the rest of the site is already configured for /shop /cart /register, etc.

Comment: Read this article https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/

Comment: How do you configure the rest of the site? Do you want to make the USERID as the first parameter in global routing?

Comment: @Karney. Yes, we'd like the USERID to be first in global routing, but also optional if possible so that users can go to any route normally and not be affiliated with any input USERID. Basically an optional affiliate id in the first parameter spot.